# searchCriteriaBuilder using multiple sort

Tags: magento2, search-criteria

I've been experimenting with SearchCriteriaBuilder but I can't seem to get the syntax right to apply multiple sort.

I've tried this

```
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(EntryInterface::STATUS, 1, 'eq');
$sort = [];
$sort[] = $this->sortOrder->setField(EntryInterface::COUNTRY)
    ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);
$sort[] = $this->sortOrder->setField(EntryInterface::SORT)
    ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);

$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setSortOrders($sort);
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
return $this->entryRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
```

And this...

```
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(EntryInterface::STATUS, 1, 'eq');
$sortOne = $this->sortOrder->setField(EntryInterface::COUNTRY)
    ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);
$sortTwo = $this->sortOrder->setField(EntryInterface::SORT)
    ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);

$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setSortOrders([$sortOne, $sortTwo]);
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
return $this->entryRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
```

One more I tried

```
[...]
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setSortOrders([$sortOne]);
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setSortOrders([$sortTwo]);
[...]
```

But only one sort applies.

I've checked the docs and I'm still unsure.

Is it possible to apply multiple sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work for you is that $this->sortOrder is a singleton object. So $sortOne and $sortTwo are referred to the same object.

```
$sortOne = $this->sortOrder->setField(EntryInterface::COUNTRY)
    ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);
$sortTwo = $this->sortOrder->setField(EntryInterface::SORT)
    ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);
```

The solution here is to use SortOrderFactory to create $sortOne and $sortTwo object. E.g.

```
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(EntryInterface::STATUS, 1, 'eq');
$sortOne = $this->sortOrderFactory->create()->setField(EntryInterface::COUNTRY)
    ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);
$sortTwo = $this->sortOrderFactory->create()->setField(EntryInterface::SORT)
    ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);

$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setSortOrders([$sortOne, $sortTwo]);
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
return $this->entryRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
```

FYI, I've also created 2 dummy examples at the webroot folder on a default Magento sample data to prove it. See them [here](https://gist.github.com/toanthree/228d1d59843a805cae4e836ea77a4ae4)

I hope that it helps.

Comment: This answer is 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

Full working example based on other answer

```
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Xigen\Estimator\Api\Data\EntryInterface;
use Xigen\Estimator\Api\EntryRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Xigen\Estimator\Api\EntryRepositoryInterface $entryRepositoryInterface
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderFactory $sortOrderFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        EntryRepositoryInterface $entryRepositoryInterface,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        SortOrderFactory $sortOrderFactory
    ) {
        $this->entryRepositoryInterface = $entryRepositoryInterface;
        $this->sortOrderFactory = $sortOrderFactory;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Get estimates
     * @param country
     * @return array
     */
    public function getEstimates($country = null)
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(EntryInterface::STATUS, 1, 'eq');

        if ($country) {
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(EntryInterface::COUNTRY, $country, 'eq');
        }

        $sortOne = $this->sortOrderFactory->create()
            ->setField(EntryInterface::COUNTRY)
            ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);
        $sortTwo = $this->sortOrderFactory->create()
            ->setField(EntryInterface::SORT)
            ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);

        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setSortOrders([$sortOne, $sortTwo]);
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        return $this->entryRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
    }
```