# collection filtter not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection

> collection fillter

```
    $prodColl = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $prodColl->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                       ->addAttributeToFilter('activity', ['eq'=>'1'])
                       ->load();

echo '<pre>'; print_r($collection->getData());
```

Comment: remove ->load(); and try it.

Comment: okey i will remove->load

Comment: is it working?.

Comment: Ya it is working -@RohanHapani thanks for help

Comment: Okay. I added as answer so it will helpful for other. You can accept and upvote answer :)

Comment: I updated :) Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove load() method and check it :

```
$prodColl = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $prodColl->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                       ->addAttributeToFilter('activity', ['eq'=>'1']);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($collection->getData());
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('activity', array('eq' => 1));
```

Comment: why need to first initiate and then, create new object?

Comment: As Rohan spotted - not quite right. To explain : Create() is used with classes to create new object instance. Whereas get() is used to retrieve cached object instance. So you don't need to do both and potentially outcome could be different especially when chaining. Someone gave me a good example of this recent https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/311286/70343.

Comment: Also don't use object manager and factory method. Just object manager and the collection class - basically the other answer.